# HighCharts - Spline Chart Legend Color

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change the color of my legend in my spline chart.

[image]

As you can see, my series have different colors but the labels for each one are a dark gray and on my background its basically invisible. Googled for a while and came up with nothing. I want to each title to make the line color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all legends colors in `legend.itemStyle`

```
legend: {
    itemStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49pog49x/)